# cut string and put the result itself

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I have a file cve.txt with these examples:

```
delta.x
alpha.tri
blue.zia
```

I want to cut the string until dot and put itself like:

```
delta.x|delta
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F. '{ print $0"|"$1}' input
delta.x|delta
alpha.tri|alpha
blue.zia|blue
```

We tell `awk` that `.` is the field separator, and then compose the output as you describe with the simple `print` statement.  `$0` is the input line; `$1` is the first field (i. e. everything preceding the first `.`).

Answer (score 1):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/\([^.]*\)\.[^.]*/&|\1/' file
```

The output:

```
delta.x|delta
alpha.tri|alpha
blue.zia|blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a `cut` solution:

```
paste -d\| input <(cut -d\. -f1 input)
```